# Battery life on netbook with Linux Mint 10 vs 11

Tags: ubuntu, ssd, linux-mint, battery-life

I have bought a new SSD for my Eee1000HE, and want to run Mint on it (I prefer the look and feel over Ubuntu). I read somewhere that the version 11 ran on some newer version of the kernel that had a bug in it that concumes a lot of power? If I just focus on battery life will I then be better off running the previous version? Or is Ubuntu actually better on battery life?

As I have understood, all mentiononed versions have TRIM support, so there is no need to take into account that I am running on a SSD. Is that correct?

(And please do not recommend distributions other than Mint and Ubuntu. Yes, I am probably closed minded who do not want to spend the extra time getting into some super duper distro who solves all my problems, but I do not want to spend the next six months in a terminal. I am comfortable with Mint and Ubuntu, and want to stick with those. My loss, maybe, but usability goes a long way.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there has been a power issue with the most recent kernels, 2.6.38 was the baseline, and .39, 3.0 and 3.1 [have issues](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_31_power_regress&num=1).

So if you are planning to use any distribution, check the kernel version being used and whether the distribution devs have fixed in the kernel they ship (I am not aware of any that have fixed it).

**Update**

May be a while until fixed release dists get [this update](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/opinion/software/3319456/new-kernel-patch-slashes-linuxs-power-appetite/), as they tend not to do big kernel jumps between releases.